# Regex to select the exact letter after an integer and avoid the proceeding comma of the selected text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regex which recognized the letter **d** which is **placed after an integer** within an text (the d letter which is in the middle of the text). But at the moment it selects the next proceeding letter after letter **d** as well (whatever the letter it selected anyway). In this case it selects the proceeding comma as well (see the attached image)

Regex validation URL - https://regex101.com/r/ozlvQy/1

[image]

I just want the selection to be stopped if an comma is met (text without the comma should be selected). I guess that the current inserted regex can be altered to meet this.

I am very bad at regex calculations and will be great if anyone can help here ?

Comment: You need `d(?!o)`, see https://regex101.com/r/9NIpSC/1

Comment: It selects every d letter in the text. But I want only the d letter which is proceeding after an integer value to be selected

Comment: No, judging by the question, you do not. You have not even tried to check for a digit. In my demo, I enables the global modifier, and thus got all matches (your regex would do the same). Here is a demo with no `g` modifier: https://regex101.com/r/9NIpSC/2.

Comment: works as charm. thank you